# Implementation of Multiple language based on url specific

Tags: django, multilingual, django-multilingual

I am using *language translation* in my project.But it only translate the strings if I set the highest priority to respective language in my browser.

*e.g.*

If i am using two language **en** and **es** for translation then it will display data in *spanish* if I have *set spanish as my default language* in my browser.

My translation is working because it only displayed that data in spanish which i have specified in my Django.po file.

So What i want is if i specify the language in url as www.asd.com/?lang=es then it must display the data in spanish.

So please suggest me what i have to do for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking [django-localeurl](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-localeurl/1.5).

> *A Django application that allow you to specify the language of a page in the URL.*

For [Installation click here.](http://packages.python.org/django-localeurl/setup.html)

Comment: if i installed it the files which i have to edit is only url and settings file